# LikewiseOpen and pam_access

Tags: active-directory, rhel5, pam, sles11, likewise-open

We have a combination of RHEL5 and SLES11 servers that integrate with Active Directory via LikewiseOpen. What I'm wondering is in what place should I put the pam rule to allow pam_access to be correctly used as part of the authentication of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best Would be in the "common-account" file.

Comment: Hm, "common-account" is for accounting, meanwhile pam_access isn't, is it?

Comment: yes ,your Correct its for Account.your String would be **account  required       pam_access.so**.you can either put it in your /etc/pam.d/login or your common-account as other files reference it.